# Write BLE Attribute Value to iPhone (Bluez)

Tags: ios, iphone, core-bluetooth, dbus, bluez

I used the following article **https://dobots.nl/2014/07/23/linux-and-le** to validate the ability to connect, read and write an attribute value from Bluez to an iPhone. I'm running the latest Bluez stack (5.25) and the LightBlue app to simulate the BLE service. I perform the following steps:

- **sudo hcitool lescan** (locate the Service)
- **sudo attrib/gatttool -t random -b 68:8A:02:D1:32:72 -I**
- **connect** (connect to bluez stack)
- **char-desc** (list out characteristic descriptions)
- **char-read-hnd 0x0031** (read the attribute value to update)

> [68:8A:02:D1:32:72][LE]> char-read-hnd 0x0031
>   Characteristic value/descriptor: 01

- **char-write-req 0x0031 00** (write attribute value)

> ```
> [68:8A:02:D1:32:72][LE]> char-write-req 0x0031 00
> Error: Characteristic Write Request failed: Attribute can't be written
> ```

I did set the attribute permissions to ***read, write and notify*** so that attribute value can be properly accessed. But, I keep getting the message: **Error: Characteristic Write Request failed: Attribute can't be written**.

I plan to create a BLUEZ DBUS C Program to write attribute to my iOS app. ***Is it possible to write an attribute value defined within an iOS app from Bluez?***.

I'm able to perform these steps with an TI SensorTag device. I've also been able to connect from the iPhone to Bluez and update Attribute Values but I would like to perform this directly via Bluez.

Comment: I don't much about LightBlue or Bluez, but you must enable the write property on the characteristic, which is part of the advertising data.

Comment: I did set the attribute permissions within the LightBlue app to read, write and notify. I've also used a sample iOS app and assigned the same attribute permissions. I does not seem to help.

Comment: This could be a long shot, but have you tried connecting to the LE device with: `sudo hcitool lecc 68:8A:02:D1:32:72`

Comment: I have tried `sudo hcitool lecc 68:8A:02:D1:32:72` but that did not work. Most article contributors stated that this was no longer required for the later Bluez 5.x releases. For example, see this article: **stackoverflow.com/questions/22213793/bluetooth-le-on-raspbian**.